# Jypyter QTconsole not returning error messages

Tags: qtconsole, jupyter-console

Am i missing something? I did get newest Winpython (WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5) package and when i'm trying to run code with %run code in QTconsole everything goes well but error messages are not printing to console. Am i using %run all wrong or is it bug? I'm using windows 7

Comment: I'm having same issue.  Very easy to reproduce -- create a script that raises exception then use %run magic.  qtconsole acts like nothing unusual happened.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Looks like bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Its bug. You can follow this issue and progress [here](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues/140)